# Who owns the iframe tag between the site creating the tag and the site who's contents are in the tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've just been wondering where the boundry for scripts of the iframe contents lie. Which element is the highest parent of the iframe contents. The iframe itself or the "html"

I tried the following but then I realize the scripts inside the iframe can't access the iframe element properties, and no warning is thrown.

The following script resides inside the iframe.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(document).on('click', '.subscribe_submit', function(){
        console.log($('.iframe').attr('data-test'));
//////////// data-test returns undefined for this.
</script>
```

while the iframe is like this.

```
<iframe data-test="$2y$12$PPuMZWPdy.zhaVnGWV7SD.Tqhw87qLe4e.vaTtWuIccxLrUFu/cda"></iframe>
```

*This is cross-origin. 
*In data-test, is not a password, I just used the PHP password API to encrypt that string.

Answer (score 2):

The browser `window` owns all.

`frames` are a property of the `window` and within frames are separate windows.

Similarly the `document` for your page is a property of the window.

Browser security rules dictate what you are or aren't allowed to do based on the domain of the main window as well as what frames are allowed to do with regard to interacting with any higher level window.

Within your page (document) you should have no problem accessing the iframe tag and setting or getting attributes. There are however frame blocking headers that pages can set to prevent being loaded within another frame

Need more details to troubleshoot why you aren't able to get the value of the data attribute

Comment: fix the jquery selector to be tag not class and see what happens. Might be a typo problem?

Answer (score 1):

The host page owns the iFrame element. If the contents are on another domain, the contents are bounded at their own "window" which sits inside the iFrame.